# Content sliding wrong way when using jQuery Show/Hide met

Tags: jquery

I am having a weird behavior with jQuery Show/Hide Methods.

I have a div that is floating to the right (css Float:right)

If this div I am trying to show/hide is NOT fixed (css position:fixed) the methods work fine.

But after scrolling the page and fixing the div in position, when I hide it, the panel hides to the right but the contents of this panel hide to the left.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="BotonRecursos" id="BotonRecursos"><img src="next-icon.png" width="32" height="32" id="Image7"/></div>
<div class="bloaqueCompleto">
    <div class="bloaqueIzq float_Izq" id="bloaqueIzq">
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bloaqueDer float_Der" id="bloaqueDer">
      <ul>
        <li>Listitem</li>
        <li>Listitem</li>        
        <li>Listitem</li>
        <li>Listitem</li>
        <li>Listitem</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.float_Izq { float: left; }
.float_Der { float: right; }

.bloaqueIzq
{
    width: 620px;
    min-height: 420px;
    border-right:1px solid #DBDBEA;
}

.bloaqueDer
{
    width: 330px;
}

.bloaqueCompleto
{
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 420px;
}

.BotonRecursos
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    margin-left:960px;
}

 .fixedP {    
    position: fixed;     
    top: 32px;    
    margin-left: 630px;    
}     
 .fixedB {    
    position: fixed;     
    top: 0px;    
}
```

And finally this are the JQuery methods I am calling

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // ***** Iamgen ocultar/mostrar panel de recursos *****
    var state = true;
    var sidebarWidth = $("#bloaqueDer").width();

    $("#Image7").click(function () {

        if (state) {
            $("#bloaqueIzq").animate({ width: "+=" + sidebarWidth + "px" }, 1000);
            $("#bloaqueDer").hide(1000, function () {
                $("#Image7").attr("src", "prev-icon.png");
            });
        } else {
            $("#bloaqueIzq").animate({ width: "-=" + sidebarWidth + "px" }, 1000);
            $("#bloaqueDer").show(1000, function () {
                $("#Image7").attr("src", "next-icon.png");
            });
        }

        state = (state) ? false : true;

    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // check where the shoppingcart-div is  
    var offset = $('#bloaqueDer').offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        // check the visible top of the browser     
        if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
            $('#bloaqueDer').addClass('fixedP');
        } else {
            $('#bloaqueDer').removeClass('fixedP');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // check where the shoppingcart-div is  
    var offset = $('#BotonRecursos').offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        // check the visible top of the browser     
        if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
            $('#BotonRecursos').addClass('fixedB');
        } else {
            $('#BotonRecursos').removeClass('fixedB');
        }
    });
});
```

You can see this behavior in action in this test I have hosted on my 
website. (the green arrow shows and hides the panel).

http://www.siinfod.com/jQuery/prueba.html

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks! .

Comment: Post updated, thanks for the advise.